# HLA - Printing out variables with stdout.put

Tags: assembly, hla

I'm starting to learn assembly and I'm using the Art of Assembly Language book.

I'm having problems trying to run an example in the book. This is the program here:

```
program DemoVars;
#include( "stdlib.hhf" );

static
      InitDemo:     int32 := 5; 
      NotInitialized:   int32;

begin DemoVars;
// Display the value of the pre-initialized variable
stdout.put( "InitDemo's value is ", InitDemo, n1 );

// Input an integer value from the user and display that value
stdout.put( "Enter an integer value: " );
stdin.get( NotInitialized );
stdout.put( "You entered: ", NotInitialized, n1 );

end DemoVars;
```

When I try compile it, it gives me four errors at the lines where the program is suppose to print the values of the variables like:

```
stdout.put: unknown data type
<n1 is type "">.
Near: << > >>

This output type is not supported.
Near: << > >>
```

Could someone help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix: Change n1 to `nl`  ("which is new line")